# Using grant proposal for applying to faculty position

Tags: funding, faculty-application

My grant application for independent research as a PostDoc got recently funded in Germany (the position started at the beginning of this year). This grant required me to choose host labs to work at. I had written the proposal by myself, with inputs from the host professors in Germany regarding the language and phrasing.

Concurrently, I have also started to apply for faculty positions in different countries. The institute at the very top of my list asks specifically for a research proposal which will play a key role in the selection process.

Since the PostDoc grant proposal is filled with many unsolved and interesting problems from my research career (in Mathematics), I would like to reuse it for my faculty application as well.

I have a few questions regarding this:

(1) What is the code of conduct around such a situation where I want to reuse the grant proposal in a faculty-position research proposal? I have never been in this situation, and I am completely unsure of how to proceed.

(2) If I am allowed to reuse the material from the grant proposal, how closely can I use it in the faculty proposal? A lot of thought and time was invested into the phrasing of the original grant, and it very concisely written. If possible, I would like to stay close to the original phrasing.

Of course, the faculty proposal will several new problems as well. Maybe, this question has an obvious answer, in which case I apologise for it. Any ideas/thoughts are very welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reuse the material". What material? Is it just what you write in the application, or something else?

Comment: Reuse the material from the postdoc grant proposal in the research proposal required for the faculty application. Hopefully the edits clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is something tricky that I can't see, there should be no problem, though I'd suggest some rewording, just to make things clear.

For example, the grant covers "work in progress" perhaps, rather than "work to be done".

But the important thing is to be clear in the faculty application about what is past, present, and proposed for the future. I think you will be in a strong position if your "Statement of Purpose" is a continuation of a research program that is already in progress and has seen some results.

I think that the rewording, rather than just copying, would make it stronger.

I hope I'm not missing something.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Buffy. I will use the phrase 'work in progress', wherever it applies.